# Why porting an iOS App to tvOS does not work?

Tags: ios, xib, tvos

I am trying to port my iOS application to tvOS. I followed step explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489992/how-to-extend-ios-app-to-tvos) to create a new target for tvOS. On compilation I get following error

```
iOS xibs do not support target device type "tv"
```

Do I have to make change in xib or create new UI from scratch for tvOS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

iOS xibs and storyboards are not supported on tvOS. However, you can tweak them manually to make them work.

> [...] One of the biggest limitations is that the tvOS project will not
>   even compile if there are iOS XIBs or storyboards present.

Here is a nice [tutorial](https://waynehartman.com/posts/convert-ios-xibs-to-tvos.html) that might solve your problem.