# tvOS deployment target absent

Tags: tvos, deployment-target, objc-bridging-header

I am working on my first tvos. Need suggestions from experienced developers as I dont see many solution available on net. 
My worry is in my project setting ,info tab, it says no macos or ios target found. How can I change it to tvos? Beside this I have followed the steps given [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489992/how-to-extend-ios-app-to-tvos/40481251?noredirect=1#comment68206928_40481251](http://here) and ported my iOS app. But I am stuck with one error that is 
 'Contentful/Contentful.h' file not found

```
#import <Contentful/Contentful.h>
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header
```

And I tried all possible settings but still not solved. Please do guide me if anyone's aware about deployment target and Bridging header issue. Please please do help me out,I have been trying for last 2 days.

Comment: Can you provide full code of your Bridging header?

Comment: Thanks Roman for reply,but issue is solved. I am posting a reply so it may help someone. As bridgin header issue does not exactly point at particular reason in my case  bridging header issue is solved by installing all the pods which support tvos and removing few pods which dont support tvos. I had done the same thing earlier too but one difference was I installed beta version of cocoapods which support tvos and then installed all pods. To install cocoapods here is the command ' sudo gem install cocoapods --pre '